# lodash Groupby based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, angular2-services

i am using angular 4 for one of my projects and i have a situation where i have to group the data based on multiple conditions as explained below.

Raw data

```
[
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street1"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to group data based on both age and address field so the result would be something like

```
{
 stree1: [{
        age: "12",
        details: [
            {
                address: "street1"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        age: "12",
        details: [
            {
                address: "street1"
            }
        ]
    }

    ],
        street2: [{
            age: "12",
            details: [
                {
                    address: "street1"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
```

I know we can use lodash to group the data based on single condition like

```
_.groupBy(data, 'age');
```

But i am not understanding how to do this based on multiple conditions. I want to group all those objects which has same address and same age. Something like

```
_.groupBy(data, 'age' && details[0].address);
```

How to go about this. Please help.

Comment: whar if some of them having age 14? can you give expected output?

Comment: I understand why you asked the question .. Is there any way to output only those objects which has a match and discard those which doesnt have a match. ie in the given example, the street2 data wont even be there ...

Comment: so if there is multiple object with the combo value of street + address then only it will appear with grouping? is it?

Comment: and also, `detaills` array will have oly one object? or other entry can be there?

Comment: yeah , details will always have one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your object structure will be exactly the same always and will have only one object in `details` then you can directly do Stringify to identify the combo, if your object have several data, then you can create a new object `{age: value, street: value}` and stringify it to identify the combo. However I will strongly suggest not to use any pipe or anything as deliminator, and joining them to create unique combination of string to find a group. Sometimes that can spoil your value.

Here is what you need:

`_(rawData).groupBy(JSON.stringify).filter(arr=>arr.length>1).mapKeys(v=>v[0].details[0].address).value()`

Here is an working example:

```js
var rawData = [
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street1"
        }
    ]
}];

var result = _(rawData)
                .groupBy(JSON.stringify)
                .filter(arr=>arr.length>1)
                .mapKeys(v=>v[0].details[0].address)
                .value();
                
console.log('Expected result: ', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Here is what you do if there can be multiple other things in your object

```js
var rawData = [
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    age: "12",
    details: [
        {
            address: "street1"
        }
    ]
}];

var result = _(rawData)
                .groupBy(obj=>JSON.stringify({age: obj.age, address: obj.details[0].address}))
                .filter(arr=>arr.length>1)
                .mapKeys(v=>v[0].details[0].address)
                .value();
                
console.log('Expected result: ', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I still have a question even after giving this answer. You want those data where the combo of address and age is occurred, but then you want to have only addrss as a key, now assume there is 2 Object with `address: street1, age 10`  and 3 objects with `address: street2, age 30` then the key will be same for both the gruop right?? so basically that cannot be, ultimately you will loss your data as the next key will override!!

Comment: Yes , thats fine in my situation as the data will be sorted based on priority before hand

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
const res = _.chain(arr)
    .groupBy('age')
    .mapValues(ageArr => _.groupBy(ageArr, ageObj => ageObj.details[0].address))
    .value();
```